# compilation error- enum within a class

Tags: c++, enums

Im having a compilation error and i cant figure why.
I have enum declaration on the .h file and the .cpp file suppose to use it inside `stringToEnum()` function

this is the .cpp file

```
#include "A.h"

A::A(void)
{
}

A::~A(void)
{
}       

values A::stringToEnum (string inputString) {
    if (inputString == "string1") return val1;
    if (inputString == "string2") return val2;
}
```

this is the header file

```
class A
{
public:

    A(void);
    ~A(void);


private:
    enum values{
        val1,
        val2,
        val3,
        val4
    };
    values stringToEnum (string inputString);
};
```

this is the error I get:

```
1>c:\users\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\A.cpp(25): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'A::stringToEnum'
1>c:\users\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\A.cpp(25): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\users\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\A.cpp(25): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\users\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\A.cpp(25): error C2556: 'int A::stringToEnum(std::string)' : overloaded function differs only by return type from 'A::values A::stringToEnum(std::string)'
1>          c:\users\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\A.h(22) : see declaration of 'A::stringToEnum'
1>c:\users\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\A.cpp(25): error C2371: 'A::stringToEnum' : redefinition; different basic types
1>          c:\users\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\A.h(22) : see declaration of 'A::stringToEnum'
```

I will be happy for some guidance.

thanks

Answer (score 7):

Since `values` is contained in `A`, you need to qualify the name:

```
A::values A::stringToEnum (string inputString) {
//...
```

Comment: thanks! every "new type member" inside the class, is supposed to be used by className::newType?

Comment: Inside the definition you can just use `values` and `val1` etc. If you want to be forced to type `values::val1` change `values` to a C++11 enum class.